# Is it possible to run memtest86 on gem5?

Tags: memory, bios, gem5

Memtest86 being a memory testing program run just after BIOS, is it possible to run memtest86 on gem5 fs mode( gem5 se will not be useful as there is no BIOS there).

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What have you tried, and how did it fail? :-)

Comment: The problem is i have executed images in the format .img on gem5 , its working fine but the problem is this time my executable is the format of .efi ( (Extensible Firmware Interface) .

Comment: well my command was:  build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/prakhar/full_system_images/disk/linux-x86.img --kernel=/home/prakhar/full_system_images/binaries/BOOTX64.efi           the result was:  Could not load kernel file